# What may cause MS Query (msqry32.exe) to crash when I try to use MySQL ODBC driver?

Tags: mysql, excel, connection, ms-query

I need to import some data to Excel from MySQL DB via MS Query *(using MySQL ODBC driver)*.
At the first step I set up Data Source name, TCP/IP server, port, username, password and schema name.
When I pressed the Test button, the connection worked fine. Next, I selected the table name, needed columns, filters, sort order and get to the `Query Wizard - Finish` screen. Regardless of choosing `Return data to Excel` or `View data in MS Query`, after pressing the `Finish` button, I get an MS Query crash.

I'm giving problem details below:

> Problem Event Name: BEX64
>   Application Name: msqry32.exe
>   Application Version: 15.0.4128.1014
>   Application Timestamp: 4fe552e8
>   Fault Module Name: myodbc5.dll
>   Fault Module Version: 5.1.11.0
>   Fault Module Timestamp: 4f9b1ada
>   Exception Code: c0000409
>   Exception Offset: 00000000000053de
>   SO Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>   Locale ID: 1033
>   Additional Information 1: 7877
>   Additional Information 2: 78776f05532d6948ecde3d2d80dd0f86
>   Additional Information 3: 0bcb
>   Additional Information 4: 0bcb9f9d2da69b06627ca9d789f2a3fe

In additional, the DB is remote and I connecting via VPN.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a known bug if there are long tables names, is that a possible cause?

Comment: I have the same problem, any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the 64 bit mysql driver. This will cause unexplained behavior (i.e., crashes) when used with the 32 bit office suite.

Comment: 1. I tried to use x64 version of mysql driver with x64 office suite and then - both x86 version of driver and suite. Nothing works. 2. I noticed that I can easily use other Databases - f.e., local DB on localhost.